# mysql query find sets which element match to another sets element

Tags: mysql

My tables are  like below format

## User table

```
> id  username  interest_ids
> 1   Ram        1,2,3
> 2   Suja        2,3,
> 3   Rahul       2,4,5,6
> 4   nipa        1,4,6
```

## Interest Tables Like

```
id   name
1    Music
2    Book
3    News
4    T.V watching
5   Song
6   Dancing
7   Game
```

now i want to search user who have same interest. 
example `Nipa` is a user whose interest id are `1,4,6` 
and interest ids match with user `Ram (id 1)and Rahul(id 3)`

What is mysql query so i can fetch users who has similar interest id like nipa.

Comment: Your DB design suffering from `Normaloporosis` needs immediate normalization.

Comment: You should show what you have already tried at least and explain if you have a problem with that...

Comment: Fields with comma separated fields should be avoided as much as possible : you see how complicated it will be to manage a query like this one. List the different interest names for a user is also really complicated. You should create a `user_interest` relation table, with a `user_id` and a `interest_id`

Comment: ihave  25 interest in interest table  if i create another user_interest table and 10000 user are there and they choose 10 interest average then i should insert 10000* 10 ... so i thing store interest data in set is smart way

Comment: it isn't smart. it's stupid and lazy. 100,000 rows isn't a big deal.

Comment: thanks guys for reply. but i am able to create sql query which give me perfect result. Searching other stack over flow answer and they give me idea about create sql query with my same table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables were normalised properly (WHICH THEY SHOULD BE! DO IT!) and you had a user_interests table that looked like this:

```
create table user_interests (
  user_id integer,
  interest_id integer
);
```

Then your answer would be:

```
select distinct username
  from users u
    inner join user_interests ui
      on u.id = ui.user_id
  where ui.interest_id in
    (select ui2.interest_id
       from users u2 
         inner join user_interests ui2
           on u2.id = ui2.user_id
       where u2.username = 'Nipa'
    )
    and u.user_name <> 'Nipa'
```

As it stands, mysql can't split strings without a lot of effort that would be better spent fixing the tables.

[Here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b07789/5)